# DB adapter creating instance regularly

Tags: soa, oracle11g, jdeveloper, bpel

I have created a BPEL process and added a DB adapter for polling a table change of new row added..
and my polling interval is 60 seconds,
but my process is creating an instance on every 60 seconds, ideally when table have some change then it should create an workitem in application..

please guide me if i am doing any thing wrong...

Comment: I see that your questions are about scenarios one would encounter when using Oracle-SOA suite. I do not have answers to your qs, but have a suggestion. Post your questions on a more specific forum: http://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=320, and you are sure to get some answers. Also, please post any useful answers here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume if you look at the instances that are created you will notice that you are getting the same data back.

This will occur if the db adapter is unsure what records have been read.

The simplest way to do this is to have the DB adapter mark the record as read.  You can do this by adding an indicator column to your schema as one solution that is set to read or unread.

But effectively, your issue is most likely, without further information, that you are re-reading the same record every iteration and therefore you need to use one of the options for determining a record has been read.